# Service returning Kerberos error but only when using FQDN

Tags: kerberos, fqdn

I have an issue that was brought to me by another in our office. He is troubleshooting a service our software uses with customers environments that try's to make a connection to SQLServer2 by use of a service on a specified port. It first calls to SQLServer1 to retrieve the correct AD information then uses the FQDN it has just received from the call to establish a constant connection to SQLServer2. This works completely correctly when the value in SQLServer1 is changed to the IP address that the service is calling for but not with the FQDN. It returns a Kerberos error "The Kerberos client received a KER_AP_ERR_MODIFIED error from the server informconsole. The target name used host/domain.local"

Does anyone know what may be causing this error and how to fix it? At this point we thought it was a network error but all network traffic can be validated as correct. All connections between each of the nodes are solid and can be verified as reachable through ping and tracert.

Comment: At first glance, I'd be investigating SPN's

Comment: If I'm reading up correctly an SPN has to be unique and this could just be a matter of that SPN being used in multiple places?